# Value doesn't change $on

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue working on this https://github.com/poillic/marvelApi/tree/master/server

I need to update my pagination when I recieve the datas but my $scope.creators array doesn't seems to be modified.

Here is the code :

```
$scope.creators = [ { firstName: 'test', middleName: 'peter', lastName: 'po'} ];


$scope.setCreators = function( creators ){
    console.log(creators);
    $scope.creators = creators;
};

$scope.getCreators = function( page ){
    var query = {
        offset: page * $scope.limit,
        limit: $scope.limit
    };

    console.log( query );

    $http({
        url : baseURL+'/creators',
        params : query,
        method : "GET"
    }).success(function(data){
        if( data.data.results ){
            $scope.setCreators( data.data.results );
        }

        $scope.total = data.data.total;
        $scope.nbPages = ($scope.total / $scope.limit) | 0;

        var pageData = { 
            total: $scope.total,
            limit: $scope.limit
        };
        $scope.$broadcast( 'pagination', pageData );
    }).error(function(){
        console.log('Get creators error');
    });
};

$scope.getCreators(0);

$scope.$on('pageChanged', function(e, data){
    $scope.getCreators( data.page );
});
```

The first `$scope.getCreators()` is called everything works fine. But in `$scope.$on` it looks like a `$scope.creators` is modified but not the good one.

Comment: The problem is most likely due to the using $timeout. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Also, your $scope.nbPages not be total/limit instead of total/offset?

Comment: I removed `$timeout` and edited total. But it still  doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post your changes? Also consider adding a console.log inside the if( data.data.results ) to make sure that you are actually getting results back.

Comment: Post edited and this is what data.data.reults log http://i.imgur.com/ibeVs6R.png

Comment: Try changing console.log(creators); to console.log(JSON.stringify(creators)); . Then compare what is printed the first time the getCreators() method is called to what is printed after you start changing the pages. If the output is the same, then the problem is that the API is returning the same results.

Comment: The API doesn't return the same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85130/discussion-between-gpicazo-and-prox).

Answer (score 0):

Answer found with the help of GPicazo.

The problem that I defined two controller for the same view.
One time in the html view and another time in the routes.